In Konsole, Asian file names are displayed as escaped sequences
I'm using Arch Linux with KDE Plasma. The system's locale is English. Korean/Japanese fonts are installed. In Dolphin, files with korean/japanese names are shown correctly. But in Konsole, their names are displayed as espaped sequences like ''$'\355\205\214\354\212\244\355\212\270''.txt' In Konsole's profile, the default encoding was already set to UTF-8.
How to solve?


The output of strings /proc/$$/environ | grep -e LANG -e LANGUAGE -e LC_ | sort
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8

The output of locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


locale charmap was showing some sort of ASCII. The problem was solved when it was changed to UTF-8. I don't remember how I did it exactly, because I tried a few things.

Which shell are you using? Is it bash, or something else? What is the output of locale or strings /proc/$$/environ | grep -e LANG -e LANGUAGE -e LC_ | sort if run within Konsole? Is there a difference between the outputs of the two commands?

@telcoM It's ZSH and I installed Oh My ZSH.

The error messages from locale suggest that the actual locale data may not have been successfully generated for the en_GB.UTF-8 locale.
Check your /etc/locale.gen file: make sure the line that says
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8

is uncommented, and then run locale-gen as root. If there are any error messages, what do they say? Does running locale-gen fix the problem? (you might have to open a new Konsole window to see the effect)
Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Locale

I had already uncommented that and Korean/Japanese. I ran the gen command again, and the output was : Generating locales...
en_GB.UTF-8... done
ja_JP.UTF-8... done
ko_KR.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
